# Dockerized Flask & React App: Missing bundle.js in dist Directory Post-Deployment

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, webpack

I am deploying a Dockerized application with a React frontend and Flask backend in GCP App Engine.
The issue I'm encountering is that after deployment, the bundle.js file, which should be located in the frontend/dist directory, is not being found. This problem occurs both on DigitalOcean Droplet and on Google App Engine.
**Locally, the dist and the files in it get emitted and are found.**

Project Structure:
React sources in frontend/src
React build output in frontend/dist (including bundle.js)
Flask application in root/api

Dockerfile Summary:
Build stage with Node.js: Compiles React app, outputs to frontend/dist.
Production stage with Python: Copies frontend/dist to container, serves with Flask.
Problem:
bundle.js is confirmed to be in dist after build (via ls -l dist in Dockerfile), but it's missing when the app is deployed.

Why might bundle.js disappear from dist after deployment, despite being present post-build? Are there specific Docker or deployment configurations that might cause this?

Attempts to Resolve:
Verified that bundle.js is created during the build process.
Confirmed the dist directory path in the Dockerfile.
Checked for any .dockerignore configurations that might exclude dist.
Ensured that there are no permission issues with the dist directory.
Simplified the Dockerfile for debugging purposes.

I still can't see why bundle.js is not found by my flask app, or when I ssh into my build.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        // Replace style-loader with MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // Use the HTML file in 'public' as a template
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
      // Output filename (defaults to 'index.html' in the output path)
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Output filename for CSS
      filename: 'styles.css',
    }),
    function () {
      this.hooks.done.tap('DonePlugin', (stats) => {
        console.log('Output file path:', stats.compilation.outputOptions.path);
      });
    },
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,
  },
};
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python38
service: default
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT api.app:app --log-level=debug
```

Flask

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='/app/frontend/dist', static_url_path='')
...
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def serve(path):
    if path != "" and not path.startswith('api/'):
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')
    else:
        return "API route or 404"

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    try:
        # Check if the path starts with 'api/'
        if path.startswith('api/'):
            # Here you can handle your API routes or simply pass
            pass
        # For non-API paths, serve static files or index.html for SPA routing
        else:
            return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, path if '.' in path else 'index.html')
    except Exception as e:
        # Log any exceptions that occur during the request
        logger.error(f"Error serving '{path}': {str(e)}")
        return jsonify(error="The requested URL was not found."), 404
```